# "Cant start new thread" problema con python y multi hilos

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

De antemano gracias por su tiempo.
Tengo un programa en python3 el cual en un loop mantiene cada cierto tiempo unas consultas:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("|Root| Iniciando sistema x")
        print("|Root| ...")
        hiloMain = MainClass()

        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        hiloMain.detenerMainThread()
        print("|Root| hilo main detenido")
```

este por ejemplo es como inicia el programa, lo que da paso a que inicie el loop

la siguiente es el init de la clase MainClass

```py
def __init__(self):
        self.mainThreadLife = True
        self.dispositivosArray = []
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("|MainClass| Main Class iniciada")
        print("|MainClass| Instanciando tarea de estado")
        self.clientBoto = boto3.client('lambda',
                                       aws_access_key_id="xxxx",
                                       aws_secret_access_key="xxxx",
                                       region_name="xxx")

        self.requestObject = urllib3.PoolManager()
        self.cargarConexionMysql()
```

finalmente el loop:

```py
def run(self):
        print("|MainClass| ...")
        while self.mainThreadLife:

            print("|MainClass| ============== se inicio consulta de dispositivos ============== ")
            self.descargarDispositivos()
            sleep(15)
```

la descarga del dispositivo no es mas que la creacion de un objeto con las variables del gps que en su interior contiene un hilo que al ejecutarse a traves del poolManager visto anterior mente hace consultas tipo POST.

descargarDispositivos: (miren dispo.iniciarThread())

```py
def descargarDispositivos(self):
        sqlBusquedahd = '-----'

        con = self.obtenerConexionLibre()
        print("|Conexion pool| conexiones libres: %s " % (self.conexionPool.size()) )
        #with self.conexionMysql.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute(sqlBusquedahd)
        hardwareArray = cursor.fetchall()

        cursor.close()
        con.close()
        print("|Conexion pool| conexiones libres: %s " % (self.conexionPool.size()) )


        print("|descargarDispositivos| tiempo de ejecución Server(UTC) : %s" % (datetime.datetime.now()))
        print("|descargarDispositivos| tiempo de ejecución Colombia(GMT-5) : %s \n" % (datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=5)))
        print("|descargarDispositivos| cantidad de dispositivos: %s \n" % (len(self.dispositivosArray)))

        for i in range(len(hardwareArray)):
            if hardwareArray[i]["xxx"] is not None:
               self.comprobarDispositivoNuevo(hardwareArray[i])


def comprobarDispositivoNuevo(self, hardwareItem):
        if len(self.dispositivosArray) > 0:
            isCreated = False

            for dispo in self.dispositivosArray:
                if dispo.rtnPlacaIDHardware() == hardwareItem["xxx"] and dispo.rtnTipoVehiculo() == hardwareItem["xxxx"]:
                    dispo.updateDispositivo(hardwareItem)
                    dispo.iniciarThread() ## ESTE ES EL PUNTO DEL ERROR
                    isCreated = True
                    break

            if not isCreated:
                nuevoDispositivo = DispositivoClass(hardwareItem,self.conexionPool,self.requestObject)
                nuevoDispositivo.setBotoLambda(self.clientBoto)
                nuevoDispositivo.setMunicipios(self.municipios)
                nuevoDispositivo.setGeoCercas(self.geocercas)
                nuevoDispositivo.iniciarThread()

                self.dispositivosArray.append(nuevoDispositivo)    

        else:
            nuevoDispositivo = DispositivoClass(hardwareItem,self.conexionPool,self.requestObject)
            nuevoDispositivo.setBotoLambda(self.clientBoto)
            nuevoDispositivo.setMunicipios(self.municipios)
            nuevoDispositivo.setGeoCercas(self.geocercas)
            nuevoDispositivo.iniciarThread()

            self.dispositivosArray.append(nuevoDispositivo)
```

el error ocurre justo en dispo.iniciarThread() 
el cual es este:

```py
def iniciarThread(self):
        if hasattr(self,"thread"):
            if self.thread.is_alive() is False and self.tPyP.is_alive() is False and self.tObligaciones.is_alive() is False and self.tPlacaGeocercas.is_alive() is False:
                self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
                self.thread.daemon = True
                self.thread.start()
        else:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
            self.thread.daemon = True
            self.thread.start()
```

basicamente la funcion vuelve y corre el run que esta dentro de la clase de DispositivosClass

este es el dato curioso.
yo ejecuto el programa, y este dura estable unos 4 dias. sin embargo, tira el error de "cant start new Thread" justo ahi y el numero de hilos activos que saco a traves de la funcion threading.active_count() siempre me da unos 14 a 20 hilos vivos justo antes de que colapse.

yo realmente no apago el hilo pues tengo entendido que el run de dispositivo al no contener un loop este muere cuando ejecuta su ultima linea.

```py
def run(self):
        self.consultarToAmberDevice()

def consultarToAmberDevice(self):

        encoded_data = json.dumps({
            'xxxx':self.dispositivoObject["xxxx"],
            'xxxx':self.dispositivoObject["xxxx"],
            'xxx':'xxxx'
            })


        try:
            consulta = self.requestObject.request('POST',
                                              'http://xxxx',
                                              headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                                              body=encoded_data)

            respObj = json.loads(consulta.data.decode('utf-8'))
            respObj = respObj["xxx"]

            self.amberResult = respObj
            #print("=======\n")
            #print("consultado amber: %s "%(self.dispositivoObject["xxxxx"]))
            #print(respObj)
            #print("=======\n")

            consulta.release_conn()

            self.tPyP = threading.Thread(target=self.consultarPosicion,args=())##THREAD DE PYP
            self.tPyP.daemon = True
            self.tPyP.start()

            self.tObligaciones = threading.Thread(target=self.consultarObligaciones,args=())##THREAD OBLIGACIONES
            self.tObligaciones.daemon = True
            self.tObligaciones.start()

            self.tPlacaGeocercas = threading.Thread(target=self.consultarGeocercasByUser,args=())
            self.tPlacaGeocercas.daemon = True
            self.tPlacaGeocercas.start()

        except Exception as error:
            print("|ERROR| Dispositivo %s| error de consulta" % (self.dispositivoObject["xxx"]))
            print(error)
```

estoy olvidando algo? muchas gracias por su ayuda.

PD: el error siempre siempre se da justo en el iniciarThread, los hilos internos del dispositivos tampoco contienen loops, todos los hilos mueren segun lo esperado, pero el error surge...

Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

El error que indices "Can't start new thread" la mayoría de veces se da cuando ya tienes muchos hilos, y por alguna limitación de recursos ya no puede crear más.

Lo normal es que puedas llegar a tener cientos de hilos abiertos al mismo tiempo, pero me desconcierta porque dices que suelen haber unos 14-20 antes de colapsar, y eso es bastante poco. Quizá puedes revisar esta parte. ¿Seguro que son solo unos 20?

Otra cosa que tal vez ayude es que revises cuándo se abren y cierran los hilos, tal vez se te esté escapando algo y algunos hilos se queden abiertos o algo así. Y quizá también ayude revisar el control de errores, ¿qué pasa cuando hay errores el hilo se está cerrando? ¿O se queda abierto?, etc. Espero que te ayude en algo.